# UDF in HiveQL in 'From' statement

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Is it possible to use UDF in Hive QL in 'From' statement ?
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM getTableName();
```

where getTableName() is a some kind of UDF that will return different table names based on some business rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. UDFs are evaluated as a part of Map Reduce job. Hence this query will give you an error.